# I recently found that my inbox emails are not showing up on my Android

Tags: applications, email

I tried adjusting settings to select inbox default but it's not working.  I can ready messages on my laptop, but they simply are not showing up on my smart device.  I get a message saying "You're all done.  Have a good day".  But I'm not having a good day....

Comment: Okay...kinda can help until you provide more information...What kind of phone?  What application are you using to view your mail?  Is this a Google account, Exchange account, Office 365...?

Comment: It's an LG K7 and I use Google Gmail.

Comment: And if I select All Messages on the drop-down, I can then read them. But my default, Primary, does not automatically bring up the list of messages, like it was doing a few days ago.